# Can every computable number be listed?

Tags: computer-science, computability

Computable number is countable. Does this mean computable number can be listed one by one?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, that's what countable means. What's more, if you are in possession of a proof of the countability, you can probably derive a listing from it.

Comment: Yes, of course they can be listed. Start with listing all the finite sequences of bytes. Scratch out those that are not programs in your favourite programming language. Further scratch those which don’t take an integer (say $n$) of input or don’t produce a finite decimal number $r(n)$ on output, or hang. Then scratch those for which $r(n)$ does not converge, or for which $r(n)$ is not an approximation of the limit up to $10^{-n}$ accuracy. Now scratch those that produce a limit already produced by an earlier program. The list you get gives you programs to approximate all computable numbers.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Countable means there exists a bijection to $\mathbb{N}$, not that we can actually find said bijection and list them.

Comment: Note I am not saying you, or I, or anyone, can do this process. It may be impossible to determine, for a program on the list, whether it can hang, or whether the approximations $r(n)$ it produces converge. But this does not negate the conclusion.

Comment: @Jair, I know what "countable" means. I make a distinction between "they can be listed" and "we can list them."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on what you mean by "can be listed".  In set theory, a set $S$ being countable means that *there exists* such a "list", or more specifically, a bijection $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow S$.  However, just because such a bijection exists doesn't mean we can actually determine a specific, concrete, *computable* example of such an $f$.  In the case of computable numbers, we know that such a bijection exists because there is a bijection $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow B$ where $B$ is the set of finite binary strings, and every computable number can be formed by running a universal Turing machine on this binary string as input.  However, some of these binary strings $b \in B$ will not result in a computable number, because they might not ever halt: they might *start* a number, like 34.34... but then never give you a third digit and continue computing forever. (or they might produce nonsense output like $34.34.2.$)  In abstract, we can define a bijection $g: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow C$, where $C$ is the set of computable numbers, by saying $g(1) = $ (the first computable number produced by such a $b$), $g(2)$ being the second computable number produced after the first, and so on inductively; these numbers must exist, because of the property of the natural numbers that every nonempty subset of $\mathbb{N}$ must have a first element.  However, in practice we cannot say which binary strings $b$ will give rise to a computable number, because a Turing machine cannot solve the *halting problem* of telling which Turing machines halt. Depending on the specifics of the universal Turing machine you are using, you *might* be able to identify $g(1), g(2), g(3)$, say, by some ad-hoc process of elimination and case-by-case analysis of a large set of binary strings, but you won't be able to get very far.